# Returning a bool value to a main function

Tags: c++, function, boolean, return

Ok, So my problem is im dropping a 1000MM rod 0-999 inclusive. simulating 2 random break points using the rand function. Taking those 2 break points to calculate three broken pieces.
Then checking those three broken pieces to see if they form a triangle and returning a bool value of true or false to the main function depending on if they formed the triangle or not.

The issue im having is with returning the bool function and displaying it in my main function.

Any help id like to thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

bool triangleCheck(int & side1, int & side2, int & side3);
void generateRandomNumbers ( int & breakLocation, int & breakLocation2);
void calculateBrokenSides (int & breakLocation, int & breakLocation2, int & side1, int & side2, int & side3);




void main ()
{


srand(time(NULL));
int breakLocation, breakLocation2, side1, side2, side3;


generateRandomNumbers (breakLocation, breakLocation2);
cout << breakLocation << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << breakLocation2 << endl;


calculateBrokenSides ( breakLocation, breakLocation2, side1, side2, side3);
cout << side1 <<" "<<side2 <<" "<<side3<< endl;

triangleCheck (side1, side2, side3);
}




void generateRandomNumbers(int & breakLocation, int & breakLocation2)
{

//make 2 random break locations
do  {
breakLocation = rand() % 999 +1 ;
breakLocation2 = rand() % 999 +1 ;
} while(breakLocation == breakLocation2 );

}


// this function takes the 2 random numbers symbolizing break points and calculates 3 lengths of broken glass then returns them using pass by reference
void calculateBrokenSides (int & breakLocation, int & breakLocation2, int & side1, int & side2, int & side3)
{

if (breakLocation < breakLocation2)
(side1 = breakLocation +1) && (side2 = breakLocation2 - (breakLocation +1)) && (side3 = 1000 - (side1 + side2));    
else 
(side1 = breakLocation2 +1) && (side2 = breakLocation - (breakLocation2 +1)) && (side3 = 1000 - (side1 + side2));  

}   




//This function tests the three lengths of glass created in generateRandomNumbers and CalculateBrokenSides to see if they form a triangle
bool triangleCheck(int & side1, int & side2, int & side3)
{
if (side1 + side2 > side3 || side2 + side3 > side1 || side1 + side3 > side2)
return true;
else
return false;}
```

Comment: Why can't you display it if you call it directly in `main()`?

Comment: probably not helpful, but I'd simplify triangleCheck to {return (side1 + side2 > side3 || side2 + side3 > side1 || side1 + side3 > side2);} without the conditionals

Comment: You might be interested in [`std::boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha).

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice.

```
if(triangleCheck (side1, side2, side3))
    cout << "YAY True" << endl;
else
    cout << "WRONG..Sorry" << endl;
```

Comment: thanks, looks like i might have another issue in my code but that fixed that problem